# RDLC report Group by below another group by

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

Object I want to set on the report

```
public class SurveyTemplateReportModel
{
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string QuestionName { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Field { get; set; }
}
```

Report Structure

```
**Topic 1**
**Section 1**

QuestionName 1.0
Question 1.0
Field 1.0

QuestionName 1.1
Question 1.1
Field 1.1

**Section 1.1**

QuestionName 1.1.0
Question 1.1.0
Field 1.1.0

QuestionName 1.1.1
Question 1.1.1
Field 1.1.1

**Section 2.0**

QuestionName 2.0.0
Question 2.0.0
Field 2.0.0

QuestionName 2.0.1
Question 2.0.1
Field 2.0.1

QuestionName 2.0.2
Question 2.0.2
Field 2.0.2
```

Can anyone help me setup this kind of report

Answer (score 0):

c# code would look like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<SurveyTemplateReportModel> model = new List<SurveyTemplateReportModel>() {
                new SurveyTemplateReportModel() { Topic = "1" , Section = "1" , QuestionName = "1.0", Question = "1.0", Field = "1.0"},
                new SurveyTemplateReportModel() { Topic = "1" , Section = "1" , QuestionName = "1.1", Question = "1.1", Field = "1.1"},
                new SurveyTemplateReportModel() { Topic = "1" , Section = "1.1" , QuestionName = "1.1.0", Question = "1.1.0", Field = "1.1.0"},
                new SurveyTemplateReportModel() { Topic = "1" , Section = "1" , QuestionName = "1.1.1", Question = "1.1.1", Field = "1.1.1"},
                new SurveyTemplateReportModel() { Topic = "1" , Section = "2" , QuestionName = "2.0.0", Question = "2.0.0", Field = "2.0.0"},
                new SurveyTemplateReportModel() { Topic = "1" , Section = "2" , QuestionName = "2.0.1", Question = "2.0.1", Field = "2.0.1"},
                new SurveyTemplateReportModel() { Topic = "1" , Section = "2" , QuestionName = "2.0.2", Question = "2.0.2", Field = "2.0.2"}
            };

            foreach (var topic in model.GroupBy(x => x.Topic))
            {
               Console.WriteLine("**Topic {0}**", topic.Key);
                foreach (var section in topic.GroupBy(x => x.Section))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}**Section {1}**", new string(' ', 5),section.Key);
                    foreach (SurveyTemplateReportModel survey in section)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}QuestionName = {1}, Question = {2}, Field = {3}", new string(' ', 10), survey.QuestionName, survey.Question, survey.Field);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class SurveyTemplateReportModel
    {
        public string Topic { get; set; }
        public string Section { get; set; }
        public string QuestionName { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string Field { get; set; }
    }
}
```